# Inserir uma Partial View @Html.Partial em um iframe

Tags: asp.net

Preciso inserir uma Partial View de asp.net mvc em um `iframe` mas a View não esta abrindo.

Alguém pode me dar alguma dica?

Já tentei o código abaixo, mas não deu certo:

```
iframe src="@Html.Partial("_AGD")" height="500" > /iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie uma Action no seu Controller para retornar esta Partial View, e no `href` do seu do `iframe` aponte para para a sua action.

Exemplo:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Agd() {
    return PartialView("_AGD");
}
```

**View**

```
<iframe src="@Url.Action("NomeAction", "NomeController")" height="500" />
```

Comment: caraca, uma coisa tao simples, vlw meu amigo!
desculpa a ignorancia!
abração!

Comment: @PauloFreitas Magina, a comunidade aqui é para isso mesmo. Se a resposta lhe foi útil, se puder marque-a como aceita √, assim quando outros usuários visualizarem sua questão verão que já tem uma resposta correta e aceita por você